# want to find a encode format to improve performance of websocket for web game

Tags: serialization, websocket, protocol-buffers

I use json as the serialize format that runs on websocket in my web game at first.
But there are so much redundancy in json. So I want to find a more effective format to serialize my object.

And then I found protojs(https://github.com/sirikata/protojs) which implements protobuf in javascript. But its encoding performance is so poor (about 20+ times of json) since javascript dose not support type cast and it has to do a lot math operations to convert the primary data type (such as double) to bytes to do the protobuf encoding. The result turns out to be that request in protojs is much slower than in json.

Is there any good idea to improve the efficiency of data communication on websocket in web game?

Comment: Are you sure this is where your performance bottleneck lies? How much data are you sending?

Comment: Have you tried using gzip compression?

Comment: It's not the bottleneck. I just think that json is not so effective and very curious about that which serialization formats are used in current web games :)

Comment: I hasn't tried gzip yet. I am finding a gzip lib that can be use in javascript, but I just can't get one. Any good lib recommend?

Comment: JSON is natively handled in Javascript.  This seems like premature optimization, or at least a case of reinventing the wheel.  gzip would be good to decrease data being sent, but it'll slow down your code...

Comment: yes, json is optimized by javascript engine natively and gzip may meet the same problem of protojs.

Answer (score 0):

I recently attended [onGameStart](http://ongamestart.com) ([write-up here](http://blog.pusher.com/2011/9/26/ongamestart-a-bright-future-for-html5-games)) and [Rob Hawkes](http://twitter.com/robhawkes) of Mozilla and [Rawkets](http://rawkets.com/) fame mentioned [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) (Binary JSON). However, he did say that he wasn't 100% sure if it improved efficiency.